# Function help in c++

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to create a very simple function in c++ however I keep getting a "Link error".

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;


int fun(int,int);

main(){
    int width,height,w,h,mult;

    cin>>width;
    cin>>height;

    mult = fun(width,height);

    int fun(int w,int h);{
        w * h ;
        }

    cout << mult ; 

}
```

The error:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `fun(int, int)' 
ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: your implementation of fun is in the wrong scope, you need to put it outside of main.

Comment: You also are trying to define your function `fun` inside `main`. Try moving the code before `cout << mult ;` out of `main`.

Comment: is the intention for the block of code right after the call to fun to be the implementation of fun? it almost looks like trying to use delegates (C#) in c++ code... is there something like that I don't know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ack...so many things wrong with that. Should be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int fun(int, int);

void main(){
    int width,height,mult;

    cin >> width;
    cin >> height;

    mult = fun(width, height);

    cout << mult << endl; 

}

int fun(int w, int h) {
    return w*h;
}
```

(Been awhile since I touched C++)

Comment: Thanks, It's hard to piece together this kind of thing from the intelligible notes I took in class :\

Comment: Take neater notes ;) Especially when it's code... one typo and it won't compile.

Answer (score 6):

There is no implementation of `fun(int, int)` anywhere.  The module which implements it should be linked in with this.  Or you should write the function in the module above, perhaps where the prototype is.

It appears there is a failed attempt to define the function midway:

```
int fun(int w,int h);{
    w * h ;
    }
```

What this actually does it declare (again) that there is some function `int fun()`:  that is a prototype. Then there is an expression `w * h`, still inside function main which is evaluated but nothing is done with the result.

Comment: There is. As a subfunction of `main`. Which is not a good idea given that the declaration is at outmost scope.

Comment: is correct - this is not a function definition of any sort.  Did everyone spot the semicolon?  (Yes, if the semicolon were removed the code would still have similar problems, for the reasons already explained.)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a global function fun, and you define it inside main. You should declare it outside, or remove the external declaration

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the function outside the main()